# In Python, how do I find keys in an array of dictionaries where the values are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.8.  I have an array of dictionaries, all of which have the same keys ...

```
list_of_dicts = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": "zz"}, {"a": 1, "b": "2"}]
```

How do I return a list of keys in which all the values are identical?  For example, the above would be just

```
["a"]
```

since all three dicts have "a" = 1.

Comment: List != array in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in other answers, create a master dictionary that groups each key, then check their uniqueness.

```
# all keys are the same, so get the list
keys = array_of_dicts[0].keys()

# collapse values into a single dictionary
value_dict = {k: set(d[k] for d in array_of_dicts) for k in keys}

# get list of all single-valued keys
print([k for k, v in value_dict.items() if len(v) == 1])
```

Comment: Only doubt here is... Are all keys the same? From the example it seems so but it is not shown as a mandatory requirement.

Comment: @Pitto Seemed to be stated by OP that they were

Comment: Note, `.keys()` is not necessary. Iterating over a `dict` iterates over its keys anyway. It doesn't return a list of keys, btw, it returns a set-like view of the keys in a dict. Also, if you *are* going to do it this way, you can use a set comprehension: `{d[k] for d in array_of_dicts}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my additional answer of @JaonHax.

```
array_of_dicts = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": "zz", "c": "cc"}, {"a": 1, "b": "2"}]

def get_same_vals(dicts):
  keys = []
  for key in dicts[0].keys():
    is_same = True
    for each_dict in array_of_dicts:
      if not key in each_dict or  each_dict[key] != dicts[0][key]:
        is_same = False
    if is_same:
      keys.append(key)
  return keys

print(get_same_vals(array_of_dicts))
```

Comment: Ah, yeah. Was in a rush to just get the answer out, so didn't think of adding `key in each_dict` to that conditional. Good thinking.

Comment: Thank you @JaonHax

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, it will work also in case that the dictionaries are differently structured (have different / extra keys):

```
array_of_dicts = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": "zz"}, {"a": 1, "b": "2"}]

def is_entry_in_all_dicts(key, value):
    identical_entries_found = 0
    for dict in array_of_dicts:
        if key in dict:
            if dict[key] == value:
                identical_entries_found += 1
    if identical_entries_found == len(array_of_dicts):
        return True
    return False
                
result = []
for dict in array_of_dicts:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if is_entry_in_all_dicts(key, value):
            if key not in result:
                result.append(key)
print(result)
```

**Output**
['a']

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain that they all have the same keys, you can iterate through their keys and the list like so:

```
array_of_dicts = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": "zz"}, {"a": 1, "b": "2"}]

def get_same_vals(dicts):
  keys = []
  for key in dicts[0].keys():
    is_same = True
    for each_dict in dicts:
      if each_dict[key] != dicts[0][key]:
        is_same = False
    if is_same:
      keys.append(key)
  return keys

print(get_same_vals(array_of_dicts))
# Prints ['a']
```

I apologise for the inefficient code; I didn't spend that long coding this up.

Comment: Adding an extra key to the list of dicts will make it crash

Comment: @Pitto That's why I prefaced it by saying that if we *know* they *all* have the same keys, you can use this simple option.

Comment: Each dict will have exactly the same keys so this assumption is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If every dictionary has the same keys, you can combine the values into sets and find the sets with one element:

```
[list(x.keys())[0] for x in [{k:set([e[k] for e in list_of_dicts])} for k in list_of_dicts[0]] if len(list(x.values())[0]) == 1]
```

Output:

```
['a']
```

Answer (score -1):

Append your N dictionaries into a giant dictionary, and check for keys that have N identical values:

```
giant_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in (e for d in list_of_dicts for e in d):
    giant_dict[k].append(v)
for k, v in giant_dict.items():
    if len(v) == len(list_of_dicts) and all(e == v[0] for e in v):
        print(k)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a more succinct approach

```
from functools import reduce
array_of_dicts = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "c": "zz"}, {"a": 1, "d": "2"}]
result = reduce(lambda a, b: a.intersection(b),list(map(lambda x: set(x.keys()), 
                array_of_dicts)))
```

Comment: Why are you using `list(map(...))`? Note, `set(x.key())` should just be `set(x)`, so really, it should just be `map(set, array_of_dicts)`

Comment: Also, this doesn't do what the OP asked, which is to get the list of keys where *all the values* are the same. You are just getting a list of common keys

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I didn't read the question thoroughly. You are correct, I am just returning a list of keys common to all dicts in array_of_dicts.

Answer (score -1):

Group your values into a set, then figure out which keys have a set with length 1:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> list_of_dicts = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": "zz"}, {"a": 1, "b": "2"}]
>>> grouped_values = defaultdict(set)
>>> for d in list_of_dicts:
...     for k,v in d.items():
...         grouped_values[k].add(v)
...
>>> [k for k,v in grouped_values.items() if len(v) == 1]
['a']
```